# get previous and next hours limit for dynamic time constraint

Tags: java, datetime

I am working on a simple java application in which I have to set a time limit constratint. In my application I have to only allow for routes to be found within a 4 hours range, for example, if a driver has posted a route for 3pm, the rider would only find it if he search for the times between 11am (4 hours before) and 7pm (4 hours later). I am using 12 hours time format in the application. My code for this is:

```
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
                    Date driverTimeLimit = null;
                    Date riderTimeCompare = null;
                    try {
                        driverTimeLimit = parser.parse(driver_Time);
                        riderTimeCompare = parser.parse(rider_Time);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal.setTime(driverTimeLimit);
                    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
                    cal.getTime();

                    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal1.setTime(driverTimeLimit);
                    cal1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -4);
                    cal1.getTime();
    if(riderTimeCompare.compareTo(cal.getTime())<=0 && riderTimeCompare.compareTo(cal1.getTime())>=0){
      ...
}
```

In my above code driver_Time and rider_Time are two stings like 3:00 for driver and 11:00 for rider.

I have to put a condition which satisfies 11:00am and 7:00pm time constraints or the time should varies according to driver's time.

Please suggest some code which satify this condition including am and pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by bellow given code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String dTime = "03:00PM";
            String rTime = "11:00AM";

            System.out.println(convertTo24HoursFormat(dTime));
            System.out.println(convertTo24HoursFormat(rTime));

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

            Date dDate = dateFormat.parse(convertTo24HoursFormat(dTime));
            Date rDate = dateFormat.parse(convertTo24HoursFormat(rTime));

            System.out.println("Driver Date=" + dDate);
            System.out.println("Rider Date=" + rDate);

            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar1.setTime(dDate);
            calendar1.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);

            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar2.setTime(dDate);
            calendar2.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -4);

            System.out.println("Driver Date after adding 4 hours="
                    + calendar1.getTime());
            System.out.println("Driver Date after subtracting 4 hours="
                    + calendar2.getTime());
            System.out.println("Rider Date=" + rDate);

            if (rDate.compareTo(calendar1.getTime()) <= 0
                    && rDate.compareTo(calendar2.getTime()) >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Route acceptable");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Route not acceptable");
            }

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
        }
    }

    private static final DateFormat TWELVE_TF = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
    private static final DateFormat TWENTY_FOUR_TF = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "HH:mm");

    public static String convertTo24HoursFormat(String twelveHourTime)
            throws ParseException {
        return TWENTY_FOUR_TF.format(TWELVE_TF.parse(twelveHourTime));
    }
```